# Finder opens only when USB stick inserted

Tags: mac, finder, usb

I'm experiencing some issues with Finder after an update on my Mac (Mojave). When I click the Finder icon in the Dock, nothing happens. It does not open.

However, when I insert a USB stick, wait for it to mount and THEN click the Finder icon again (so not the USB icon but Finder itself), it suddenly appears.

Anyone seen this behavior before?

Ralph

Comment: You mean it doesn't come to the front, or that there are no visible windows? [check the menu bar for the frontmost name] Do you use Spaces? Do you have the Finder fixed to a single Space? There's a bug since about Sierra where clicking a bit of visible Desktop will not switch to the Finder's correct Space if it's different to the one you're on.

Comment: I have no spaces except the primary desktop one. If I click on Finder in the task bar, I do see the top bar (with the apple icon) flash slowly once... like it's trying to switch to another space that isn't there or something. Really weird...